# jQuery resize function with css height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I'm trying to set a height to a div that it's parent have. I've tried and when I use `console.log()` it's actually working. But the height doesn't set without a refresh.....

This is my function

```
// Set Hight
function fixingHeight() {
    function setHeight() {
        var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

        var latestPostsWrapperHeight = $('#latestPosts').height();
        var tabPane = $('#latestPosts').find('.tab-pane');
        var tabPaneLists = $('#latestPosts').find('.tab-pane').find('li a');

        var popularPostsWrapperHeight = $('#popularPosts').height();
        var profileWrapper = $('#popularPosts').find('.pofile-wrapper');

        if(windowWidth > 767) {
            $.each(tabPane, function() {
                $(this).height(latestPostsWrapperHeight - 70);
            });

            $.each(tabPaneLists, function() {
                $(this).height((latestPostsWrapperHeight - 70) / 5 - 1);
            });

            $.each(profileWrapper, function() {
                $(this).outerHeight(popularPostsWrapperHeight);
            });
        }

        //console.log(windowWidth);
    }setHeight();

    $(window).resize(function() {
      setHeight();
    });
}fixingHeight();
```

Answer (score 1):

- To handle window resize event, call the function `$(window).resize` outside of the function `setHeight()`
- to call `setHeight()` on first load, use the jquery handler `$(document).ready`

This is the final code :

```
function setHeight() {
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

    var latestPostsWrapperHeight = $('#latestPosts').height();
    var tabPane = $('#latestPosts').find('.tab-pane');
    var tabPaneLists = $('#latestPosts').find('.tab-pane').find('li a');

    var popularPostsWrapperHeight = $('#popularPosts').height();
    var profileWrapper = $('#popularPosts').find('.pofile-wrapper');

    if(windowWidth > 767) {
        $.each(tabPane, function() {
            $(this).height(latestPostsWrapperHeight - 70);
        });

        $.each(tabPaneLists, function() {
            $(this).height((latestPostsWrapperHeight - 70) / 5 - 1);
        });

        $.each(profileWrapper, function() {
            $(this).outerHeight(popularPostsWrapperHeight);
        });
    }
    console.log(windowWidth);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  setHeight();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  setHeight();
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't work......only console.log() is working as my previous code.

Answer (score 1):

- remove the function wrapper `fixingHeight()`, 'setHeight()' is enough
- `$(window).resize` dont't run because it is in a function so this is not working without calling the function wrapper, so get it outside of the function.
- as @ joram say, you can call `$(document).ready` when your document finish loading, so is ready.

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setHeight();
  });
  $(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
  });        
  function setHeight() {
      var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
      console.log(windowWidth);

      var latestPostsWrapperHeight = $('#latestPosts').height();
      var tabPane = $('#latestPosts').find('.tab-pane');
      var tabPaneLists = $('#latestPosts').find('.tab-pane').find('li a');

      var popularPostsWrapperHeight = $('#popularPosts').height();
      var profileWrapper = $('#popularPosts').find('.pofile-wrapper');

      if(windowWidth > 767) {
          $.each(tabPane, function() {
              $(this).height(latestPostsWrapperHeight - 70);
          });

          $.each(tabPaneLists, function() {
              $(this).height((latestPostsWrapperHeight - 70) / 5 - 1);
          });

          $.each(profileWrapper, function() {
              $(this).outerHeight(popularPostsWrapperHeight);
          });
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't work......only console.log() is working as my previous code.